# Is it possible to read data from multiple data sources in SSIS whose connection strings are saved in SQL table?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, oledb

Connection strings for each data source, i.e Excel, OLE DB etc. are saved in an SQL table. We need to pull each connection string at a time and then read the corresponding data source(Flat file, excel, OLE DB), check the number of records and load the same in destination SQL table.Though I tried foreach loop container in SSIS, but it worked for OLEDB, not working for Excel, flat file.

```
        try
        {
            int IsActive = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::IsActive"].Value);
            String Table = Dts.Variables["User::SourceTable"].Value.ToString();
            String ConnString = Dts.Variables["User::ConnString"].Value.ToString();
            if (IsActive == 1)
            {
                string SQL = "SELECT '" + Table + "' AS TableName, N'" + ConnString + "' AS ConnString, COUNT (*) AS RecordCount, GETDATE() AS ActionTime FROM " + Dts.Variables["User::SourceTable"].Value.ToString() + " (NOLOCK)";
                Dts.Variables["User::Query"].Value = SQL;
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ;
        }
```

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: I am working to create a package that will set up dynamic connection with multiple sources like sql, excel, flat files etc.

For this I have set up below in sql server:

1.Source_list table
which contains TableName, DatabaseName, ConnctionString, IsActive

2. Result Table which contains:
TableName, ConnectionString, RecordCount

Comment: In my package I have first taken a SQL task that fetches only ConnectionString and TableName of only IsActive=1 Records from SourceList Table. And then Written a Script task with script as below:

Comment: I have successfully setup Dynamic connections with SQL sources but stuck with Excel Sources. Could you please help to proceed.

Comment: You need to use other programming language such as C#, VB or Java.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, it would be helpful if anyone can provide a sample code snippet.

Comment: You need to stop amending your question in the comments. If the question needs changing then please change it. Furthermore, this is a very broad question to which @Dr.Stitch has given you the most accurate answer.